# Setting the creation date of each file in a folder to mach its own "last modifictaion" date automatically, using CMD, software or similar

Tags: cmd, file-management

I got a folder of about 1000 pictures and videos. The creation date of the files is incorrect, but the "last modified" time stamp is correct. I want to set the creation date of each of the files in the folder to mach its own "last modifictaion" date, automatically using CMD or any program that is capable of this.

Comment: I found this simple yet very useful program called BulkFileChanger which is cabable of replacing and copying numerous date and time information of media files
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html

Comment: you should add the path to the directory in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5

How to replace creation time with last modified time using PowerShell.

If you do not see the updated Properties-Details in your files close the Properties-Details window, hit `F5` and re-open the Properties-Details window.

To do all files in folder:

```
Get-ChildItem * | ForEach-Object{$_.CreationTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
```

Files by extension:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg, *.mkv | ForEach-Object{$_.CreationTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
```

To run the command in CMD:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem * | ForEach-Object{$_.CreationTime = $_.LastWriteTime}"
```

[image: file Properties-Details]

How to replace CreationTime with LastWriteTime for all files by extension in a folder using PowerShell 5 and a wildcard.
How to replace CreationTime with LastwriteTime using PowerShell 5 and a wildcard.